# Using a spinner to switch to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement, android-spinner

I am completely new to Java so I want to apologize and ask for your understanding for this question.
I am trying to use a spinner that can switch to other activities. Any time I run the emulator, I get an Unfortunately, your application has stopped error. Do I need to add something other than the code below to my activity I am switching to?

```
public class LakeOptions extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lake);``

}
```

Here is my code from the activity attached to the xml with my spinner on it. Do I need to add anything to the xml spinner tag? Again, I apologize for my ignorance.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.counties, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

      class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {
           switch(pos) {
               case 0:
                   Intent j = new Intent ( this, JasperOptions.class);
                   startActivity(j);
                   break;
               case 1:
                   Intent k = new Intent(this, LakeOptions.class);
                   startActivity(k);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   Intent l = new Intent(this, LaporteOptions.class);
                   startActivity(l);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   Intent n = new Intent(this, NewtonOptions.class);
                   startActivity(n);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   Intent p = new Intent(this, PorterOptions.class);
                   startActivity(p);
                   break;
           }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

                }


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    }
```

my logcat errors are as follows

```
    03-28 18:24:28.320    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K,                    5% free 3043K/3176K, paused 185ms, total 199ms
    03-28 18:24:28.480    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.472MB for 3609872-byte allocation
    03-28 18:24:28.940    1928-1937/com.helpfinder.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 6565K/6704K, paused 451ms, total 451ms
   03-28 18:24:32.030    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
   03-28 18:24:47.750    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 2% free 6769K/6900K, paused 94ms, total 99ms
    03-28 18:24:56.250    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 139 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-28 18:24:56.960    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
    03-28 18:24:57.070    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
    03-28 18:24:57.070    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=531.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2456198, downTime=2456110, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
    03-28 18:24:57.200    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
    03-28 18:24:57.200    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app W/ViewRootImpl﹕ Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=181.0, y[0]=531.0,    toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2456404, downTime=2456404, deviceId=0,  source=0x1002 }
    03-28 18:25:06.000    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-28 18:25:26.750    1928-1928/com.helpfinder.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.helpfinder.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.JasperOptions"
        android:label="JasperOptions">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.JasperFood"
        android:label="JasperFood">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.JasperHousing"
        android:label="JasperHousing">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.JasperAssistance"
        android:label="JasperAssistance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.JasperOtherServices"
        android:label="JasperOtherServices">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LakeOptions"
        android:label="LakeOptions">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LakeFood"
        android:label="LakeFood">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LakeHousing"
        android:label="Lake County Homeless Shelters"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LakeAssistance"
        android:label="LakeAssistance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LakeOtherServices"
        android:label="LakeOtherServices">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LaporteOptions"
        android:label="LaporteOptions">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LaporteFood"
        android:label="LaporteFood">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LaporteHousing"
        android:label="LaporteHousing">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LaporteAssistance"
        android:label="LaporteAssistance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.LaporteOtherServices"
        android:label="LaporteOtherServices">
    </activity>
    +
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.NewtonOptions"
        android:label="NewtonOptions">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.NewtonFood"
        android:label="NewtonFood">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.NewtonHousing"
        android:label="NewtonHousing">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.NewtonAssistance"
        android:label="NewtonAssistance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.NewtonOtherServices"
        android:label="NewtonOtherServices">
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name="com.helpfinder.app.PorterOptions"
    android:label="PorterOptions">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.PorterFood"
        android:label="PorterFood">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.PorterHousing"
        android:label="PorterHousing">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.PorterAssistance"
        android:label="PorterAssistance">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.helpfinder.app.PorterOtherServices"
        android:label="PorterOtherServices">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your logcat error. Also check you have given all activity in manifest.

Comment: ok, learning how to edit my comment here so I can. Thank you

Comment: yes, all activities are in the manifest.

Comment: edit your question post error.

Comment: i didnt format it too well, sorry, first time using stackflow

Comment: Just hit edit below the tags for the question and post you error log.Without seeing you log here are some possible reasons.1. When you launch your Main Activity it is going to automatically launch the "JasperOptions.class" (i.e case 0 in your switch) will this cause the crash? 2. DO you actually have the class files from these activities? 3. How many positions do you have in the spinner?

Comment: DO you see a "Caused by" anywhere in the error log? can you post that bit pls. The stuff you have posted is not very helpful.

Comment: I guess, you're writing your class `SpinnerActivity` in wrong place. It should be written outside `onCreate()`.

Comment: sure I will run the app again and see. Thank you

Comment: do u register all class correctly in menifest file?

Comment: now the app runs without the unfortunately the application stops error. the logcat is still the same. shree202, do I put if after the return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);?

Comment: Barun, I will show my manifest. hold on please

Comment: @user3474924 Check out my ans.

Comment: Hariharan, I did what you said, and I am rebuilding the project now, thank you. hold on, and we will see if it works!

Comment: It still does not switch to other activities, do I need to change the class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {     as well?

Comment: @user3474924 delete all those codings. use my codes.

Comment: @user3474924 did you get the result.

Comment: It Worked! You are my hero!One Hundred Thank Yous! I am so grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Change your **first element** from string array as **Select**

```
<string-array name="counties">
    <item name="id">Select</item>
    so on..
```

And after **user selecting spinner you can start activity** below codes inside `onCreate`

```
spinner.setSelection(0);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(pos) {
                  case 1:
                      Intent j = new Intent ( this, JasperOptions.class);
                      startActivity(j);
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      Intent k = new Intent(this, LakeOptions.class);
                      startActivity(k);
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      Intent l = new Intent(this, LaporteOptions.class);
                      startActivity(l);
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      Intent n = new Intent(this, NewtonOptions.class);
                      startActivity(n);
                      break;
                  case 5:
                      Intent p = new Intent(this, PorterOptions.class);
                      startActivity(p);
                      break;
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.counties, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    Intent j = new Intent(this, JasperOptions.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent k = new Intent(this, LakeOptions.class);
                    startActivity(k);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent l = new Intent(this, LaporteOptions.class);
                    startActivity(l);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent n = new Intent(this, NewtonOptions.class);
                    startActivity(n);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Intent p = new Intent(this, PorterOptions.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```